# Resources on 'Siberian language'

Tags: resource-request, constructed-language, russian, slavic-languages

[Siberian language](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5%C2%BB#cite_note-1) (Ru) is an artificial language project which used to have its wiki pages. Unfortunately, due to the bizzare political processes in modern Russia, the pages were deleted and the inventor of the constructed language was forced to remove its LiveJournal pages about this conlang as well.

Are there any other online resources regarding this interesting project?

Comment: I think the project was closed because of Wikipedia's policy rather than any politics.

Comment: What about the court decision forcing the author to close his LJ pages?

Comment: I think the relevant link is actually [Сибирские старожильческие говоры](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B). As described in the Russian wiki, the "Siberian" wiki was absurd.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about the conlang, not about the axctual Siberian dialects of Russian.

Comment: There is a lot of politics behind Wikipedia's policies. Not necessarily matching world geopolitics.

Answer (score 2):

There is the official site of the Siberian language, [Сибирска вольгота](http://www.volgota.com/govor), with its grammar, [Russian-Siberian dictionary](http://volgota.com/govor/dictionary), and texts in that language.